# All thing is Object

Tags: c#

in .Net All Thing is Object but I have question. I write a method

```
public static MvcHtmlString ObjectTable(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                              ICollection<Object> objects, ICollection<string> header)
```

but I don't add system.object and get error for add the namespace.
my question is:if all thing in .NET driven form object but why i should add the namespace?

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message that you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of adding a `using` directive is simply to allow you to use names within that namespace without fully-qualifying them.

So you don't *have* to add a `using` directive. You could write:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ObjectTable(this HtmlHelper helper, 
    ICollection<System.Object> objects, ICollection<string> header)
```

Or, as `object` is *always* an alias for `System.Object`, you could write:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ObjectTable(this HtmlHelper helper, 
    ICollection<object> objects, ICollection<string> header)
```

By the way, [not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx)...

Comment: what is"Open" type parameter?

Comment: @ShahroozJafari: Did you try searching? (To be honest, the details of the post probably aren't terribly important for you at the moment - just appreciating that there *are* other cases is the main thing.)

Comment: @ShahroozJafari: "this things" seems to include "everything about C#". You could read the language specification... or choose a book based on your experience level.

Comment: i am asp.net programmer but i feel i have problem in base c#.please help me to read a good book

Comment: @ShahroozJafari: Well my recommendation is usually C# in Depth, the book I wrote, but there are plenty of good other ones too. You really need to think about *exactly* what you want to learn.

Comment: i want learn asp.net mvc but i think need to learn base of .net . What is your opinion about the CLR via C# book?

Comment: @ShahroozJafari: It's good, but reasonably advanced (as is mine). If you're just a beginner, you might be better off with C# in a Nutshell.

Answer (score 3):

Just because everything is an `Object` doesn't mean `Object` can't be in the `System` namespace. And it is, and it follows the usual namespace rules.

(You can also use the lowercase `object` alias without `using System`, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Everything is derived from Object as you say, but System.Object is just like every other type that you want to reference in that you either have to reference it explicitly (I.e. System.Object) or by adding a using for the namespace.

To have it behave otherwise would be inconsistent with the rest of .Net and would likely cause more confusion.